# Linear programming - combining models

Tags: linear-programming

(moved it here from math.se - it wasn't getting enough love out there. Sorry!)

So, I've been assigned with modeling a multi-processor setup using linear (integer) programming. Basically, there are five processors with links between them, and the goal is to find the optimal schedule of communication/processing as to minimize the time of processing a set amount of data. The graph is as follows:

```
---
|A|
---
 |
 |
---    ---
|B|----|D|
---    ---
 |      |
 |      |
---    ---
|C|----|E|
---    ---
```

with A being the data source. Now, there are a few different scenarios (related to the flow direction and the order of sending/receiving data), and for each scenario, the inequalities representing the processing time are different.

For example, if data flows from B to D, from B to C, from D to E, and from C to E, B communicates first with C, and then with D, and E receives first from C, and then from D, the total processing time for C is equal to:

```
Tc >= Cab + Cbc + Cce + Sc*Dc //Sc is constant
```

If, however, B sends data first to D, and then to C, then it's

```
Tc >= Cab + Cbd + Cbc + Cce + Sc*Dc //Sc is constant
```

And so on. Overall, there are 10 such scenarios, and for each one there's a couple of inequalities that need to be satisfied. What I need is a way to communicate to my solver "pick one of those sets of inequalities and don't mind about the rest". I presume I'll have to use some binary variables to encode those, I've also heard something about multiplying the variables by a huge value to "simulate" a conditional, but currently I can't find a way to "merge" all those mini-models into one and let the solver pick the best scenario.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood your problem correctly: You have listed one possible scenario out of 10, is that correct? And each scenario has 2 inequalities? Also, what is Dc? And what's the difference between the C variable (as in Cab) versus the time variable Tc?

Comment: @RamNarasimhan Two different scenarios (the ASCII-art is general, the inequalities in post are case-specific). Each of them has a bunch of inequalities, more than 2 - here, one of them is shown. Dc is the amount of data that will be processed by a processor (in this case, C). Cxy represents the time that communication on link (X, Y) takes. Sorry for the confusion, the problem is quite lengthy in itself ^^

Comment: Thanks. Given two viable scenarios, how do you decide which one is the optimal one. What's the objective function trying to minimize, across scenarios? I have a formulation in mind, just want to make sure that it would work.

Comment: `min: T; T >= Ta; T >= Tb; T >= Tc; ...`

Comment: @RamNarasimhan As for the question about scenarios - I want to leave that for the solver to decide. Basically, which one can minimize the total processing time best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sketch of the formulation:

You have ten scenarios, S1 through S10

Let's introduce binary variables `Y_i` which denotes which of the 10 scenarios is in play.
So these become a `Specially Ordered Set` :

```
 Sum (over i in 1..10 )  Y_i = 1 (Only one scenario holds at a time.)
```

#### Requirement

For each scenario, there are a few inequalities that have to be obeyed. All other inequalities (applicable to other scenarios) should be ignored.

Let **M** be a big number. Say two orders of magnitude greater than the maximum possible processing time for any dataset.

#### Objective Function:

```
Min T
```

#### Constraints:

```
T >= Ta
...
T >= Tc
..
T >= Te
```

Let's use your scenario...Let's call it Scenario `s`.  For each inequality that needs to be satisfied under scenario `s`, we introduce a M(1-Y_s) term to the LHS of the greater than inequality.

#### Inequalities for scenario s:

```
Tc + M(1-Y_s) >= Cab + Cbc + Cce + Sc*Dc //Sc is constant
Tc + M(1-Y_s) >= Cab + Cbd + Cbc + Cce + Sc*Dc //Sc is constant
...
...
```

#### Inequalities for some other scenario t:

```
Td + M(1-Y_t) >= Cde + Cbc + Sd*Dd //Sd is constant
Td + M(1-Y_t) >= Cde + Cbd + Cbc + Cce + Sd*Dd //Sd is constant
..
```

#### Inequalities for scenario u:

```
...
...
and so on.
```

Depending on whichever Y_i is 1, those M(1-Y_i) terms will become zero. So the inequalities will be enforced.
For all the M(1-Y_j)..The left hand side will be a huge number, and the inequality will be always hold trivially.

The nice thing is that since the overall objective is to minimize T, which in turn is the max of Ta...Te...over all 10 scenarios, the Solver will automatically pick the most optimal scenario.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great, that sounds exactly like what I needed :) Thank you a lot!